# What is the correct terminology for repeating groups of coin flips multiple times in a simulation?

Tags: binomial-distribution, terminology, bernoulli-distribution, normal-approximation

I previously posted a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/389590/why-does-increasing-the-sample-size-of-coin-flips-not-improve-the-normal-curve-a) that is causing a lot of confusion because my terminology is incorrect.  I decided to post this question to ensure I am starting my problem with the correct terminology.

I will introduce the problem below with (hopefully) neutral terminology

> I am running a simulation for coin tosses (or flips).  In the
>   simulation, I am grouping together a number of tosses and counting the
>   heads within the group.  I would repeat this process multiple times to
>   get counts of heads for multiple groups.
>
> Example: If I have a group size of 5 and repeat the process three times:
>
> - Group 1: `HTTTT = 1`
> - Group 2: `THHHT = 3`
> - Group 3: `HHHHT = 4`

What is the accepted terminology ...

1. for a group of tosses where the number of heads are counted in the group?  Note: previously, I was referring to this as a **sample**.
2. for the repeating multiple groups of tosses?  Note: previously, I was referring to this as a **repetition**

It would be good if answers could provide authoritive references to the provided definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your simulation you want to tally up the number of successes (heads) for a series of 5 independent Bernoulli trials from 3 realization (or draws, or observations).

In R this can be done using the `rbinom(n, size, prob)` function, where `n` is the number of observations, `size` is the number of trials and `prob` the probability of success  in each trial. See also [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Binomial.html) for the function reference (I am sure this is similar in other programming languages as well).

The tallied number of successes for 5 trials can then be calculated as (assuming a fair coin):

```
> set.seed(123)
> rbinom(3, 5, .5)
[1] 2 3 2
```

In this case, we have 2 successes (first observation), 3 successes (second observation), 2 successes (third observation).

So Group 1, 2, 3 are **observations** with 5 **trials** in each observation.

---

## Edit: added illustration

Here's an [illustration](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galtonbrett#/media/File:Galton-Brett.svg) of a [Galton Board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_machine) that will make it much clearer what the differences between **trials** and **observations** are:

[image: Galton Board]

Each ball's path represents **one observation** (red arrows) passing through 6 left/right decisions or **six trials** (blue triangles) eventually ending up in one of the bins. The exact probability ($Pr$) of landing in one of the bins can be calculated using the [binomial probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) $$Pr(X = k) = {n \choose k}p^k(1 - p)^{n-k},$$ where $X$ represents a random variable, $k$ the number of successes (e.g. bounce *left*), $n$ the number trials, and $p$ the probability of the outcome of each trial.

In R you can use the `dbinom()` [function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Binomial.html) to calculate the exact probabilities of falling in each of the bins (from left to right and assuming $p=0.5$):

```
dbinom(6, 6, .5)
#[1] 0.015625
dbinom(5, 6, .5)
#[1] 0.09375
dbinom(4, 6, .5)
#[1] 0.234375
dbinom(3, 6, .5)
#[1] 0.3125
dbinom(2, 6, .5)
#[1] 0.234375
dbinom(1, 6, .5)
#[1] 0.09375
dbinom(0, 6, .5)
#[1] 0.015625
```

Or through simulation (in this case 100,000 observations and 6 trials):

```
bounces <- rbinom(100000, 6, .5)
mean(bounces == 6)
#[1] 0.01554
mean(bounces == 5)
#[1] 0.09325
mean(bounces == 4)
#[1] 0.23468
mean(bounces == 3)
#[1] 0.31349
mean(bounces == 2)
#[1] 0.23486
mean(bounces == 1)
#[1] 0.09287
mean(bounces == 0)
#[1] 0.01531
```

Comment: @ChrisSnow I added another illustration which should make the distinction between observations and trials pretty clear now.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your confusion. Things become more clear once you think in terms of *random variables, outcome sets, and realizations/observations of your random process/variable*.

**Flipping a coin**

A **random variable** is a function mapping outcomes of a random experiment to numbers. In the case of flipping a coin, we can define a random variable X, to take value 1 when the random variable takes value H, and take value 0 when the random variable takes the value T.

In this case there are only 2 possible outcomes: H or T. The set of all possible outcomes is referred to as the **outcome set** or **sample space**. In the case of flipping a coin, the outcome set consists of only 2 outcomes {H,T}.

Now that we have a random variable and the outcome set defined, we can repeat the random experiment of flipping one coin. Let's do it 3 times and observe the realizations of the random process. You may have obtained H on the first flip, T on the second, and H on the third. Your random variable, which assigns numbers to each outcome as per the above rule, will thus take on values 1,0, and 1 respectively. You now have a **sample** of three observations for the random variable X. A random variable that takes on only 2 values happens to have a special name - a Bernoulli variable.

**Flipping 5 coins**

Now let's look at a completely different random experiment - flipping 5 coins and counting the number of Heads. In this case, we can define a random variable Y to stand for the number of Heads observed in 5 tosses of a coin. The random experiment here consists of flipping 5 coins. There are 2^5=32 possible outcomes for this experiment, but only 5 possible outcomes for the random variable Y, {0,1,2,3,4,5}. Remember that our random variable Y maps outcomes of the experiment of flipping 5 coins to numbers (count of number of Heads). This mapping is described in the figure below.

[image]

You have repeated this random experiment 3 times and obtained: HTTTT, THHHT, and HHHHT. These outcomes of the random experiment map to the following values for the random variable Y: 1, 3, and 4. You now have a **sample** of three **observations** for the **random variable** Y. Such a variable, which counts the number of successes (i.e. Heads) in n repeated Bernoulli trials has a special name - a Binomial variable.

I hope this helps.